# How to extract methods from controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to extract "what I can" to the service. I have this method in the controller:

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList()
            };

            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
                return View("Login", loginViewModel);
            }

            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error loading external login information.");
                return View("Login", loginViewModel);
            }

            var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

            if (signInResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

                if (email != null)
                {
                    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        user = new ApplicationUser
                        {
                            UserName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                            Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
                        };

                        await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                    }
                    await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }

                ViewBag.ErrorTitle = $"Nie otrzymano informacji o adresie e-mail od dostawcy: {info.LoginProvider}";
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Proszę skontaktować się z supportem fryzjer@aplikacjafryzjer.com";

                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

Some properties are available only for classes that inherit from Controller, eg. ModelState or Url.
Can I extract these parts of the code too? A service can inherit from a controller, but won't it become a controller then?

------------------------------------------------------------ EDIT ---------------------------------------------------------------

Ok I tried separate my method from the controller. Below my previous code Controller:

```cs
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IEmailService _emailService;

        public AccountController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IEmailService emailService)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _emailService = emailService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //register functionality
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email,
                };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("ListUsers", "Administrator");
                    }
                    //login user
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                    //generation of the email token
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

                    var link = Url.Action(nameof(VerifyEmail), "Home", new { userId = user.Id, code }, Request.Scheme, Request.Host.ToString());

                    await _emailService.SendAsync(user.Email, "Weryfikacja adresu e-mail", $"<a href=\"{link}\">Potwierdź e-mail</a>", true);

                    return RedirectToAction("EmailVerification");
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
}
```

And my Controller now:

```cs
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController(
            IUserManager userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                (string action, string controller) = await _userManager.Register(model);
                return RedirectToAction(action, controller);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
}
```

I am sure, something is wrong. I have no idea how separate this logic from the controller, but on the other forums I heard "U have to separate your logic from the controller! Your controller have to be simple - only get request and send response, thats all!". but now, when I started rebuild my project, I am not sure isn't this more complicated...

In my service I return a tuple (???), because I have not better idea...

```cs
        public async Task<(string, string)> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            //register functionality
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    return ("ListUsers", "Administrator");
                }
                //login user
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                //generation of the email token
                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

                var link = _urlHelper.Action(nameof(VerifyEmail), "Home", new { userId = user.Id, code });

                await _emailService.SendAsync(user.Email, "Weryfikacja adresu e-mail", $"<a href=\"{link}\">Potwierdź e-mail</a>", true);

                return ("EmailVerification", "Administrator");
            }

            return ("Register", "Administrator");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to use `Url` in other custom service which is not inherit from controller. You could inject the `IActionContextAccessor` and use `IUrlHelperFactory` to create the it.  Besides, if you want to use other controller based property or method, you could refer [asp.net core source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore) and find it work and then you could write the codes by yourself.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Firstly you could inject the IActionContextAccessor in the startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Then you could use DI and factory to create the URLhelper like below:

```
public class GetRoute : IGetRoute
{


    private IUrlHelper _urlHelper;

    private IActionContextAccessor _IActionContextAccessor;

    public IUrlHelper Url
    {
        get
        {
            if (_urlHelper == null)
            {
                 
                _urlHelper = _urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(_IActionContextAccessor.ActionContext);
            }

            return _urlHelper;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
            }

            _urlHelper = value;
        }
    }

    private readonly IUrlHelperFactory _urlHelperFactory ;

 
    public GetRoute(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider, IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory, IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
    {
        _IActionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
        _urlHelperFactory = urlHelperFactory;
     }
    public string Getlink() {

       return Url.Link("default", "aaaa");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that's not exactly what I mean. I want to know which methods can be separate from the controller to my service and how I should do that? Do you think I should check to model is valid in controller or outside?

Comment: In my opinion, this is based on your requirement.  Normally, all the controller method need controller related variable. In my opinion, there is no need to separate from the controller to your service. Since only controller will contains the model validation, it is based on the view's post result.

Comment: Ok i will try separate only logic like 'if statement', 'methods identity' from the controller to my service. But I will leave in controller validation, and redirectToAction. I will edited my post when I finished.

Comment: Look at my EDIT if u can

Comment: If you want to create a custom service in asp.net core, you should follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#services-injected-into-startup). You should inject the enough service by using DI and then you should register the service.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented Service instead Interface in my controller... Now everything is ok

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer. Other folks who face the same issue could find the answer more easily.